# Playing with "this" in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, this

Given:

```
    var q = {};
    q.id = 1234;
    q.bonus = {
        'a':{
            'b':(function(){
                //i want to access q.id
                var id = this. ??? .id
            }),
        }
    };
```

What should be the ??? to access q.id.

Comment: Just use q.id, this won't work

Comment: There isn't any built-in "parent pointer".  If you want the embedded object `a` to be able to reference `q`, then you have to include it explicitly: `'a': { 'parent': q, `...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To access `q.id` in the function bound to `b` use [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
var q = {};
q.id = 1234;
q.bonus = {
  'a':{
     'b': (function(){
       //i want to access q.id
       var id = this.id;
       console.log(id);
     }).bind(q),
  }
};

q.bonus.a.b();
```

You can also use [Function.prototype.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to change the context of `this`

```
q.bonus.a.b.call(q);
```

Comment: You could also use the *call* function, I believe.

Comment: Interesting side effect, you can't use `call` on a bound function. Well you can, but it won't do what you want it to do...

Answer (score 1):

You can use call or apply to change the 'this' value.

```
var q = {};
q.id = 1234;
q.bonus = {
    'a':{
        'b':(function(){
            //i want to access q.id
            var id = this.id
        }.call(q)),
    }
};
```

Comment: This calls the function immediately

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the other answers and comments, any solution involves referencing `q` by name. Therefore, I'd just use `q.id` directly.